# Two canvases on top of each other in Fabric.js

Tags: html, css, angularjs, fabricjs

I am trying to create an image manipulation application that has two fundamental layers. The user can 'rotate' between the main and secondary layers which exist within the same location in the window. To accomplish this, I have code like this:

```
               <div ng-hide="layer != 'main'">
                    <canvas id="main-layer"></canvas>
                </div>
               <div ng-hide="layer != 'secondary'">
                    <canvas id="secondary-layer"></canvas>
               </div>
```

The Angular code shouldn't detract from the question here. Whenever the main layer is selected, the secondary layer's CSS display attribute is set to none

```
               display: none !important
```

The problem is that the selection mechamism of FabricJS does not work on the secondary layer. When I try to either `object:selected` or `mouse:down` on an object, nothing happens. The blue mouse dragging selection that happens by default is also not there.

Strangely enough, if I swap the `divs` containing the canvas, selection works on the secondary layer and 'sort of' works on the main layer (it is 'off' from where the mouse is).

```
               <div ng-hide="layer != 'secondary'">
                      <canvas id="secondary-layer"></canvas>
               </div>                   
               <div ng-hide="layer != 'main'">
                      <canvas id="main-layer"></canvas>
               </div>
```

Is there a way to actually stack canvases in FabricJS?

UPDATE:

I noticed that if I move to the secondary canvas and summon the Chrome web dev tools, the canvas works perfectly. On the other hand, if I rotate to the main canvas, that one does not work until I summon the Chrome web dev tools. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that that this was actually an AngularJS issue, not a FabricJS issue. The problem stems from the fact that whenever I rotate from one layer to the other, I call `calcOffset()` immediately without waiting for the `scope` to properly propagate to the DOM. This means that FabricJS has no idea that the canvas is there. I solved this issue by essentially waiting till the `scope` had propagated by adding:

```
$timeout(function() { scope.canvas.calcOffset(); }, 0);
```